# Replace first regex character using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace first regex character in notepad++

Ex:

```
*abc|123
 bcd|345
*efg|4567
```

Result should be

```
abc|123
bcd|345
efg|4567
```

I tried

```
Find: ^.?(.*)
Replace: \1
```

But its deleting the first character of every line.Please let me know if there any other way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is a "regex character"? An asterisk `*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove all non-word/non-linebreak at the start of the line use

```
^[^\w\n\r](.*)
```

and replace with `\1` or `$1`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `[^\w\n\r]` - any non-word char except an LF and CR symbols (most often used line break chars)
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars up to the end of the line (greedy match)
- `\1` or `$1` - a replacement backreference to the Group 1 contents.

[image]

Comment: One more question ,what if I need to do same for last character?

Comment: You may use `[^\w\r\n]$`. The `$` is an end-of-line anchor in Notepad++. Note I write `[^\w\r\n]` because `\W` can also match line break chars, and might mess up the number of lines in the documents.

Answer (score 0):

Simply escape the `*` with `\` and replace with nothing

Find what: `^\s|^\*`
Replace with: `leave it empty`

Comment: That will delete *all* of the asterisks in the file, not just those at the start of the line. Also, it will not remove the leading space before the "bcd".

Comment: @adrianHHH, , thanks buddy for reminding,,,, I just fixed my answer, working as a charm .....regards